Online English story about a wish to "banish darkness" gone wrong
Trying to find an online English story about a wish to "banish darkness" gone wrong.

I'm trying to recall a story I read online ages back which involved a world in a slow apocalypse because a hero had gotten hold of a powerful artifact to use against an evil god and, when making a wish with it, 'banished all the darkness!'...
Light (and increasingly heat) being pervasive was not good in the longer term.
IIRC, there was a self-fulfilling prophecy thing. The reason the 'evil' god was trying to get hold of said artifact was because he'd gotten a prophecy about it being used to cause great disaster, but since nobody would believe him...

My source is quite sure that it's not a published work.
No dice from TVTropes: Endless Daytime and Be Careful What You Wish For.

Wouldn't posting online be a form of publishing? Do you mean it's not a printed work? </pedant>

@FreeMan - Yes. Heh.
